# Android Take Screenshot rooted phone

Tags: android, android-screen

I am capturing screenshot from my android rooted device using

```
           Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);

           OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
           os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + "/sdcard/img.png").getBytes("ASCII"));
           os.flush();
           os.close();
           process.waitFor();
```

It works fine as long as the content on the screen is static (image etc). But when I try to take a screenshot when a video is playing, then the screenshot shows a black screen. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Did you get the solution for above problem?

Comment: @ganesh : Nope, I didn't.

Comment: Did you find any solution for video screenshot?